# Turtles move in direction of patch with pcolor = x

Tags: netlogo

I want my turtles to move in the direction of the nearest patch to themselves of a specific pcolor.

Currently the code I have for movement is:

```
;FLY MOVEMENT

to move-flies

  ask flies

  [right random 360

   forward 1]
```

As you can tell this just gives random movement. I want the movement to be in the direction of the nearest patch of pcolor brown. Ideally I would want the flies to stop on the patch when they get there, but that isn't the main issue at the moment, just getting them to direct to the nearest brown patch.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a combination of [`face`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#face), [`min-one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-one-of) and [`distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance). Here is a small sample program:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 10 patches [ set pcolor brown ]
  ask n-of 10 patches [ sprout 1 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    face min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = brown ] [ distance myself ]
    forward 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

(Of course, in real life, you may want to take the `face` statement out of your `go` loop, and you may need some sort of stopping condition for when your agents reach their destination.)

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. I'll work on some sort of stop procedure, see if I can do that myself.   May I ask.. does the code you gave make them face the nearest patch of pcolor=brown, or just one at random?

Comment: The nearest one. `min-one-of` is not random (unless there is a tie): it picks out the agent with the _minimum_ result for some reporter, in this case: `distance myself` (i.e., the nearest one).